# How to refresh a date panel of calendar? - QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

There is calender in my application web appln. 
Calender has 2 drop down list [ Month & year ] . I have written a script which select expected month and year. 
Date panel doesn't get refresh after selecting month and year. Due to this I am not able to select a correct date from respective month of selected year.It always display a date panel of current month & date of current month get selected.

When I perform above task manually then date panel get refresh as per selected month and year.

I just want a logic which will refresh date panel after selecting month and year.

Answer (score 1):

Please post some code so that it would be quick to get the solution. 
From what I read, you could try any of the two below ways:
1) Use ReplayType

```
On Error Resume Next
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2  'this would replicate manual click and select
...code to select the year
...code to select the month>
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1  'back to default
On Error Goto 0
```

The "On Error" commands are used here because sometimes a general run error might be hit on selecting anything after changing ReplayType settings.
selecting a value from a drop down using QTP isn't exactly the same as manually selecting. Thus, changing the ReplayType setting would replicate manual select and manual click.

2) If the above doesn't work, the use "click" command after you select the value from the drop down

```
...code to select the year
...code to click on the drop down
...code to select the month
...code to click on the drop down
```

Comment: Note: Please click on the "tick-mark" (that would denote this answer as "accepted") if this answers your question so that it does not remain unanswered.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for your reply...
Today our developer told us that there is a problem in calender development due to which I was facing that issue. Now he is working on it